# Deployment failed through docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

We are facing issue while deploying docker image in our application through Jenkins. Please can anybody help me out here.

```
Step 12/20 : RUN php installer
 ---> Running in 253d14820221
[91m/bin/sh: php: command not found
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c php installer' returned a non-zero code: 127
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Attached docker file-

```
ENV BUILD_ARGS=""
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install epel-release wget
RUN wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN wget https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd php56u-devel php56u-mysql php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath nodejs git make gcc*
RUN npm install -g gulp bower
RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/installer
RUN php installer
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN ["mv", "/composer.phar", "/usr/local/bin/composer"]
COPY build.sh build
RUN chmod +x build
COPY cleanup.sh cleanup
RUN chmod +x cleanup
VOLUME "/wordpress"
CMD /build
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile? It appears that php is not part of base docker image so it cannot find it.

Comment: Attached docker file in question. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So I don't know your build stage so I take the base image as centos. Looks like you have a missing enabled remi repo. May be you can try enabling remi repo and installing latest remi release too, So below two command you may need to add in your Dockerfile:  `RUN yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm` and `RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56` and see if that works for you. Also, you notice php56u altered to php.

```
FROM centos
ENV BUILD_ARGS=""
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install epel-release wget
RUN wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN wget https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
RUN yum -y install php php-opcache php-xml php-mcrypt php-gd php-devel php-mysql php-intl php-mbstring php-bcmath nodejs git make gcc*
RUN npm install -g gulp bower
RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/installer
RUN php installer
```

Comment: Thanks Deosha, It is working for me. Thanks Again for helping so quickly.